# Converting Rails 2 routes to Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Like in my first question from yesterday, I'm still doing [that tutorial](http://www.noupe.com/ajax/a-simple-twitter-app-with-ruby-on-rails-building-friendships.html).

I've  encountered another issue with the Rails 2 / Rails 3 routing differences.

So my question is: How do you "translate" this:

```
<%= form_remote_tag(:controller => "posts", :action => "create") do %>
```

to Rails 3 routing?

**Edit**: This is the error code I get :

```
Showing C:/Users/Lunasea/Web-Site/Standart/app/views/posts/_message_form.html.erb where line #5 raised: 

C:/Users/Lunasea/Web-Site/Standart/app/views/posts/_message_form.html.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting '}'
...pend=  form_tag {:controller => "posts", :action => "create"...
C:/Users/Lunasea/Web-Site/Standart/app/views/posts/_message_form.html.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '}'
...rm_tag {:controller => "posts", :action => "create"}, :remot...
C:/Users/Lunasea/Web-Site/Standart/app/views/posts/_message_form.html.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end
...action => "create"}, :remote => true do @output_buffer.safe_...
C:/Users/Lunasea/Web-Site/Standart/app/views/posts/_message_form.html.erb:12: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end
C:/Users/Lunasea/Web-Site/Standart/app/views/posts/_message_form.html.erb:14: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

The content of `_message_form.html.erb`:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <!--<% form_for product, :url => {:action => 'add_to_cart', :id => product.id}, :remote => true do %>-->
  <!--<%= form_remote_tag(:controller => "posts", :action => "create") do %>-->
  <%= form_for{:controller => "posts", :action => "create"}, :remote => true do %>
    <%= label_tag(:message, "What are you doing?") %><br />
    <%= text_area_tag(:message, nil, :size => "60x2") %><br />
    <%= submit_tag("Update") %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of `_message_form.html.erb`?

Comment: Sure it's : <% if logged_in? %>  
  
  <!--<% form_for product, :url =>  {:action => 'add_to_cart', :id => product.id}, :remote => true do %>-->
  <!--<%= form_remote_tag(:controller => "posts", :action => "create") do %>-->
  <%= form_for{:controller => "posts", :action => "create"}, :remote => true do %>
    <%= label_tag(:message, "What are you doing?") %><br />  
    <%= text_area_tag(:message, nil, :size => "60x2") %><br />  
    <%= submit_tag("Update") %>  
  
  <% end %>  
<% end %>

Comment: That's unreadable. Edit your question please instead of putting code blocks in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use a form_tag and pass `:remote => true` to it…

```
form_tag :url => {:controller => 'posts', :action => 'create'}, :remote => true
```

(Make sure you've included [jQuery UJS](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) or equivalent Prototype library, because Rails no longer includes the javascript inline like it used to.)

Answer (score 1):

I cite here from the book [Fernandez: The Rails 3 Way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321601661) section 11.13

> PrototypeHelper
>
> PrototypeHelper has been heavily modified ... The following helper methods were removed and made available in an official [Prototype Legacy Helper](https://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper)
>
> - ...
> - `form_remote_for`
> - `form_remote_tag`

That is the reason for your error. You have to translate that to the new syntax with the option `:remote => true` to indicate a remote call (AJAX).

So the following should work:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "posts", :action => "create"}, {:remote => true}) do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

See the [API for Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) and search there for `form_tag` for additional information.

Comment: The template's `form_tag` is correct, it's just that the old code is still there, between HTML comment tags.

Comment: Sorry, but in the question, he uses `form_remote_tag`, and that is not correct any more.

Comment: No, he asks how to "translate" the `form_remote_tag` to Rails 3.

Comment: Ok, I will remove the first option.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying there is a syntax problem in the message form template.   My guess is that you are missing a <% end %> to close the do in your form_remote_tag call.

Answer (score 0):

`form_remote_tag` is not there in the Rails 3

Use

```
form_tag :url => {...}, :remote => true
```

instead

> What this means is that all previous remote_ helpers have been
>   removed from Rails core and put into the Prototype Legacy Helper. To
>   get UJS hooks into your HTML, you now pass :remote => true instead.
>   For example:
>
> form_for @post, :remote => true

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html

Comment: First of all thank you all for your quick answers !

So I tried the "Prototype legacy" but somehow it didn't work...anyway I fixed by using the new synthax :

    <%= form_tag :url => {:controller => "posts", :action => "create"}, :remote => true do %>

I restarted the server and I don't get any errors and it looks fine (for now ^^) !

Thanks again !

Comment: @Ko Ichi, glad to know it helped you :D

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use `<!--` and `-->` to hide old code. Rails will still execute that code. Use the following format instead:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <%-# form_for product, :url => {:action => 'add_to_cart', :id => product.id}, :remote => true do %>
  <%-#= form_remote_tag(:controller => "posts", :action => "create") do %>
  <%= form_for{:controller => "posts", :action => "create"}, :remote => true do %>
    <%= label_tag(:message, "What are you doing?") %><br />
    <%= text_area_tag(:message, nil, :size => "60x2") %><br />
    <%= submit_tag("Update") %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```